# getting different answer in different cells of jupyter[plot of sns]

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, seaborn

let's say we have a df like below

[image: df view]

I have plotted using seaborn. After that, I have extracted the xticks data. whenever I am running in the next cell, it is showing the correct result but in the same cell, its showing diff .highlighted both . what is the reason behind this and how to resolve.

[image: ss of the result]

PFB code:
DF part--->

```
   df={'A':48,'B':12,'C':86}
   df=pd.DataFrame(list(df.items()),columns=("name","score"))
   df['score']=df['score']/100
   df
```

plotting part --->

```
   fig, ax=matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10,2))

   g=sns.barplot(y='name',x='score',data=df,ax=ax)
   ax.set_xticks([0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0])
   ax.set_xticklabels(['0.00', 'bad','ok','good','v. good'])
   ax.get_xticklabels()[1]
```

getting the xticks again in diff cell ---->

```
   ax.get_xticklabels()[1]
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text, not as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you need to use `plt.show()` before calling `ax.get_xticklabels()`. I supose this variable is not computed until the graph is generated. So if you run the following in a single cell:

```
fig, ax=matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10,2))

g=sns.barplot(y='name',x='score',data=df,ax=ax)
ax.set_xticks([0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0])
ax.set_xticklabels(['0.00', 'bad','ok','good','v. good'])
for elem in ax.get_xticklabels():
    print(elem)
plt.show()
for elem in ax.get_xticklabels():
    print(elem)
```

You obtain the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks , it worked with plt.show() in Jupyter . but  'matplotlib.use('Agg') is also present in the question , so plt.show()  is not working there . is there any other way we can compute the variable?

Comment: What you mean by "'matplotlib.use('Agg') is also present in the question"? Edit your question in case you need it pls

Comment: Please ignore my last comment .. it was another issue.. your previous answer worked .thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to replicate your issue with the code you provided. Can you retry and include the cell execution indicators on the left edge?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is also related with matplotlib configuration (for example in the `%matplotlib inline` case)